# Why does fluid stick to the outflow object?

Tags: objects, fluid-simulation

Just setting up a basic fluid simulation with an inflow object and domain. The problem is that the fluid seems to stick to the inflow object, and when drops fall, they hit the bottom of the domain and almost immediately disappear. This is my goal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VB5J4u0yMtQ

My setup and result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkbOo8CDIfc&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2):

In the example you showed, the velocity was probably set to something like 2.0 along the Z on the Inflow Sphere which means the water hits the top of the domain and runs down the sides.

[image]

[image]

Also with your Domain object, I would try experimenting with some settings.

These are the settings I set to create this scene effect. I don't know if this was more what you were looking for with yours.

[image]

I baked this with very low resolution. I'm sure with higher resolution, it would look much better but hopefully you can see the effect.

[image]